# Vim inside rails console - Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, irb

When I run a regular `irb` session I have no problems running `vim` from inside the REPL.

However, inside `rails c`, I get the following error:

```
>> vim
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
=> nil
```

Now, this is correct. My Gemfile does specify 2.1.2, and Vim is compiled with Ruby 2.0.0.

What I *really* don't want to have to do, though, is recompile Vim for each different Ruby project I'm working on that uses a different version of Ruby.

I hardly ever use the Ruby features in Vim.  Why does the Vim version I run from within `rails c` have to be compiled with exactly the same Ruby version as my Rails app?

Any way I can just temporarily disable Ruby for Vim inside IRB if the versions don't match?

I just want to be able to do simple editing with vim...

Comment: the simplest way is to use bundler `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ this does not work, see my response to your answer below

Answer (score 0):

Add `set shell=/bin/sh` to your .vimrc

Remember to restart ViM after you have updated your vimrc.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to use `bundler` as follows:

```
$ bundle exec rails c
```

or you shell to fix your `PATH` variable prepending it with proper version of `rails`:

```
$ bundle show rails
/path/to/rails/in/bundle/environment

$ export PATH=/path/to/rails/in/bundle/environment:$PATH
$ rails c
```

Comment: This doesn't affect anything...rails is already running in the bundler environment. Running rails c with bundle exec still results in the identical problem.

Comment: @MikeC8 if you think I will give an answerr better with downvote, you're wrong. It is simpler to me leave you alone with your problem. However. according the answer, provide output for `which rails` inside of the project's folder

Comment: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rails

Comment: @MikeC8 ok, then `cat $(which rails) |head -1`

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks

Comment: @MikeC8  `which ruby_executable_hooks`, and `/usr/bin/env ruby -v`, and `cat $(which ruby_executable_hooks)|head -1`